# python tkinter tag_bind not working inside loop

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
from tkinter import *

def onObjectClick(event, obj):
    canv.itemconfig(obj, width=2)

def no_onObjectClick(event, obj):
    canv.itemconfig(obj, width=1)    

root = Tk()
canv = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)

can_obj = []

w=10
ii=0
while ii < 2:
    points = [w,100, w+10,0, w+20,100]
    ln = canv.create_line(points, fill='green')
    can_obj.append(ln)
    w+=10
    ii+=1
ii=0

##this part is working fine
##canv.tag_bind(can_obj[1], '<Enter>', lambda event : onObjectClick(event, can_obj[1]))
##canv.tag_bind(can_obj[1], '<Leave>', lambda event : no_onObjectClick(event, can_obj[1]))
##canv.tag_bind(can_obj[0], '<Enter>', lambda event : onObjectClick(event, can_obj[0]))
##canv.tag_bind(can_obj[0], '<Leave>', lambda event : no_onObjectClick(event, can_obj[0]))


#this is not working as above
for obj in can_obj:
    canv.tag_bind(obj, '<Enter>', lambda event : onObjectClick(event, obj))
    canv.tag_bind(obj, '<Leave>', lambda event : no_onObjectClick(event, obj))


canv.pack()
#root.mainloop()
```

with python 3.4 on windows, it highlights only last object while use loop. but manually(without loop its work properly as used in comment section)... any solution??

Comment: Is it because of we need have all obj bind call present instead of updating it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do that inside a for loop, lambda captures the last *ID* of the last object read. As proof, if you loop over the list of your objects in a reverse order(`for obj in reversed(can_obj):`) you will notice only the most left object is acting as expected.

You can resolve your problem by using helper functions:

```
#Implementing 2 helpers
def first_helper(obj):
        return lambda event:onObjectClick(event,obj)
def second_helper(obj):
        return lambda event:no_onObjectClick(event,obj)        
#Using our helpers
for obj in reversed(can_obj):    
    canv.tag_bind(obj, '<Enter>', first_helper(obj))
    canv.tag_bind(obj, '<Leave>', second_helper(obj))
```

## Demo

Using the above code will lead you to the result you are expecting:

1. Hovering over the second object:
   [image]
2. Moving the mouse to the first object:
   [image]

Comment: You can save a few lines of code by omitting the helper methods and by binding the value at the time you create the lambda. For example:  `lambda event, obj=obj : onObjectClick(event, obj)`

Comment: Thank you very much for the useful note @BryanOakley